# Unable to open windows accessories programs from python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open snipping tool program from python.
I have used the following  code but it doesn't work:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["snippingtool.exe"])
```

It gives error "The system can't find the file specified".
I have also tried with giving full path of the snippingtool.exe i.e. `C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe`, still it doesn't work. While there is no problem with opening `notepad.exe` which is in the same folder. The same command works in Anaconda environment.

Comment: Did you try to use forward slashes instead of back slashes? Like `C:/windows/system32/snippingtool.exe` Are you 100% sure the file is present?

Comment: @Clijsters yes, the file is present and I have checked with forward slashes also , doesn't work

Comment: @Clijsters from cmd it opens without path and also with path but not from python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running 32 bit Python on a 64 bit OS then you may be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` which has no `snippingtool.exe`.

I am running on Win7 64 bit OS.

With 64bit CMD it starts `snippingtool`.

With 32 bit CMD:

```
'snippingtool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Running from Python 64 bit:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["snippingtool.exe"])
```

works.

I have no Python 32 bit installed though I would expect the same error that CMD 32 bit returns.